# Ember cli javascript notepad++

Tags: ember.js, notepad++, command-line-interface

Just learning ember cli. I opened the application.hbs in notepad++ and edited as per the instruction, trying to save but its telling me 'save failed'

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are in Windows, so correct me if I am wrong.  Try right-clicking on Notepad++ and clicking on "Run as Administrator."  Then open the file again then copy the contents of the file you edited over the contents of the new Notepad++ that you have running with administrator rights, and then try to save.